# How or can I, loop each track independently?

Tags: audacity, looping, sequencer

There's plenty of awesome music where people on analog hardware, loop overlapping tracks with inequal sizes that have prime ratios of track lengths, so that they never quite repeat at the same point.

Since the point is that they don't repeat, it would be hard to do the usual fix of duplicating each short track till it lines up perfectly with a longer track, or duplicating the longer track until you find their common factor, that won't work, since these are nonrepeating decimals and whilst computers have finite precision so an effective point of overlap will occur eventually on a digital computer, it would be very large and inefficient.

So I was wondering if there's a way to loop each track independently, or a way to make that suggestion to official audacity devs so that a dev can add it at a future date.

Sorry if this is easily fixable.

If so how?

If not, what are the next steps for doing this?

Comment: So, is this a question about the usage of audacity? Because it wasn't very clear until I read the final reference and tag (the subject should be *clearly* specified in the title or, at least, in the beginning of the topic, tags are not intended as a "main description", but only as categorization). In any case, to me this question seems a bit off topic: it's clearly not about theory, and it doesn't really fit to music practice. And, I've to say, I don't really understand what is the actual question. Are you referring to the loop playback option?

Comment: In most DAWs you just align to a bar/beat, so it doesn't drift. Not sure if audacity even has that concept.

Answer (score 1):

In audacity: select clip you want to loop, and then open menu Effects → Repeat. Then do the same for the each other clip on other tracks.

Comment: Effects->Repeat, is a way of making multiple copies. I was asking, about how to make each track loop independently rather than the silence that lasts for the difference between every other track and the longest track.

Comment: Effects Repeat, when I use it asks "repeat how many times" (paraphrasing), then you enter an integer between 1 => 1, and it makes that that many copies of that track appear.

Comment: Because for some ratios of track length: making them copied until they line up neatly, could be an actual calulation of pi. For example. That's a lot of manual repeat operations.

Comment: @user179283 Are you saying that you don't have the tracks actually cut to the length and you need some quantization tools? Then perhaps you need to use some proper DAW, rather than audacity.

Comment: Sure. I did recently get one. But that should be a feature in audacity too, shouldn't it? Audio generation like that would be wild, ya know?   Tracks that don't match should loop seperately on the same output. That should be an option atleast. But are you saying ir isn't? That's okay with me if that's that. Room for a feature suggestion I guess tho

Comment: @user179283 If you loop clips that are not the same length and their lengths ratios are not ratio of small integers, then they will not line up. It's not about audacity, it's about maths. Or I don't understand what exactly do you want to achieve. Perhaps some examples would be helpful.